I want to get a list of all the videos I have uploaded to my YouTube Channel along with the related Assets (Asset IDs) and Custom IDs
I have explored using the YouTube CMS and the YouTube APIs (Data, Content/Partner, Analytics) and I cannot find an efficient way to get a list of all the video clips that I have uploaded to my YouTube Account/Channel along with the related Assets and Custom ID (free entry field in the Rights Management section of the CMS).
The CMS seems to be limited to only recent data and I cannot find a way to do a full export of all my uploaded videos.
I have seen other SO questions and the answers help in part. For example, using the Uploads playlist, I can get a list of my Videos but this does not give me the Custom ID and does not give me the related Assets (Asset IDs).
I have used the Content ID (Partner) API using endpoints such as Assets, Claims and ClaimSearch but this returns wider claims material.
I have tried: https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/reference/rest/v1/assets/list to get a list of all my Assets but it requires the id param so it does not return all my Assets.
I have tried: https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/reference/rest/v1/assetSearch but it does not contain the Video IDs
Has anyone out there managed to achieve this query? In summary, a report containing all my Videos in my YouTube Account or Channel along with the related Assets and Custom ID values?
Any help is greatly appreciated!! Thank you

I've made progress:
1 - Use the other SO answers to get a list of Videos using the "Uploads" Playlist (https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems)
2 - Use the claims endpoint (https://youtubepartner.googleapis.com/youtube/partner/v1/claims) with the VideoId param to get the AssetId
3 - Use the assets endpoint to get the Asset metadata which holds the CustomId (https://youtubepartner.googleapis.com/youtube/partner/v1/assets/{asset_id})
This does work. Does anyone know if the CustomId is available anywhere in the Data API to avoid having to use the Content ID API?

Update - the standard video report from the CMS contain nearly all the data too, including video id and custom id. If you need analytics info such as revenue then you need to lookup to other reports, or use the other APIs
